# Required examples on Usuageof COM object Members

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and Windows COM objects.

I am able to get members of a particular COM object for example Internet Explorer as below:

```
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie | get-member
   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{d30c1661-cdaf-11d0-8a3e-00c04fc9e26e}
Name                 MemberType Definition
----                 ---------- ----------
ClientToWindow       Method     void ClientToWindow (int, int)
ExecWB               Method     void ExecWB (OLECMDID, OLECMDEXECOPT, Variant, Variant)
GetProperty          Method     Variant GetProperty (string)
GoBack               Method     void GoBack ()
```

But anywhere can I get detailed usuage of each member ?
I mean, how a particular member for example **GoBack or Busy or anyothermember** can be used in powershell scripts(in a detailed way) ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Nope. Using the get-member like that will give you all the information that you are able to get. Unfortunately there is no "Get-Help iexplore" for COM objects because they are "Black Boxes" where you only see the methods and properties that they decide are public.

Sometimes, you can infer, and experiment to get things to work. For ex.

```
#Create a new Internet explorer object
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application

#Show the Internet Explorer window
$ie.Visible = $true

#Navigate to Google
$ie.Navigate("http://google.com")

#Navigate to Yahoo
$ie.Navigate("http://yahoo.com")

#Go back to google
$ie.GoBack()
```

For anything more complex, searching google is usually the first thing I would do. For ex. some links:

- [The Internet Explorer Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970456.aspx)
- [Web UI Automation with Windows PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337896.aspx)

Comment: Yep.. doing that(experiment and search in google). 

Thanks for the reply and links :)